# Check available filters in iOS: Core Image, via Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

Within iOS it's possible to check the available filters with Objective-C, apparently like this:

```
NSArray *Filters = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn]
```

How is this check done with Swift?

Perhaps this is confusing to those down Voting and asking to close this question.

Let me phrase it another way.

I want a list of every available filter on iOS, and I want to discover that list with Swift.

That's something that should be simple enough, I'd have thought. But for two things.

1. I don't know what the difference is between builtin and plugin filters
2. It's not certain that placing "nil" (as suggested by Matt) means All filter categories, or filters that don't belong to any categories

The question, in its simplest form:

How do I get a list of available filters in iOS's use of Core Image, with Swift?

Comment: The hard part here? being me! Yes, I'd like this translated to Swift, from Objective-C. I don't always believe the documentation, and it's not always up to date. @matt

Comment: I see this part, as well as you... https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cifilter/1438145-filternames, the difference is that I don't know how to turn that into working code, nor where to write it to get an output. @matt

Comment: Ok, @matt, but how do I change the documentation's "code" into ACTUAL code?

Comment: You have 126 previous questions on Swift. How can you be claiming to be so ignorant swift basics as calling a method?

Comment: @Grundwaldeatsacoelacanth I can't make this "code" work, no matter what I do. I don't know where an output goes. I'm...

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: @matt does "nil" in your example mean "every single category!"

Comment: @matt, no, it means I have a very hard time translating method signatures into actual code. A VERY HARD TIME!!! Which might well mean the same thing, or that I have enormous trouble with all programming languages and all documentation of all languages. If method signatures and their hieroglyphics means something to you, good for you.

Comment: Trying something and it giving the desired result doesn't mean it's doing so for the reasons I'm presuming. I'm having to presume "nil" means ALL categories because... well nothing's ever explicitly explained, is it...

Comment: And, without knowing all the possible filters, how could I determine if "nil" is giving me ALL the categories of results? My gut feeling is that "nil" would give an output of all filters that don't belong to categories. @matt

Comment: @dfd the answers to all your questions are in my original question, the comments, and via a search through my SO answers and questions. A question to you... does this question, in your opinion, need a MCVE?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried? Why are you refusing to show how you attempted to translate Objective-C to Swift? And if you have, what *exactly* is the issue? Give me something I can reproduce! @Matt an be... blunt to the point of hard to cope. But you extended things - your OP (is it new? I was writing a comment when it suddenly turned into an answer that now is a screenshot of the OP) - to the point of getting personal in your OP. **That's not a good question.** Worse, it *still* shows no code whatsoever.

Comment: Translating method signatures is a mostly mechanical task, and you can get the documentation to do a lot of the work for you since you can switch it back and forth between Objective-C and Swift. People are down-voting you because they don't like being asked to do such “trivial” work. Based on [your history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2109038/confused?tab=questions&sort=activity&page=4), you've been learning Swift for over two years at this point. [It's time for you to learn some Objective-C](https://twitter.com/rmayoff/status/746873762616750080).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134914/discussion-on-question-by-confused-check-available-filters-in-ios-core-image-v).

Comment: @dfd  it wasn't Confused who edited and deleted the rant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being downvoted because [the documentation answers your question directly](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/cifilter/1437595-filternames):

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> class func filterNames(inCategories categories: [String]?) -> [String]
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> `categories`
>
> > One or more of the filter category keys defined in Filter Category Keys. Pass `nil` to get all filters in all categories.

You said ‘It's not certain that placing "nil" (as suggested by Matt) means All filter categories’, but it *is* certain, because the documentation tells you it is. You didn't read the documentation closely, and denizens of stack overflow tend to be hostile about that.

In other words, if you want all filters in all categories:

```
let allFilterNamesRegardlessOfCategory = CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)
```

Note that this could return different results than `CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: kCICategoryBuiltIn)` on iOS someday, but it cannot today because today, [only macOS supports plugin filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html).

#### UPDATE

That last paragraph is inaccurate. Since iOS 8, an app has been able to create and use its own subclasses of `CIFilter`. There is still no support for making a custom `CIFilter` available directly to other apps except on macOS.

Comment: Thank you! My searches for the differences between plugin filters and builtins was turning up air. Your last paragraph is very helpful!

Comment: And you're absolutely right about my failure to thoroughly read the documentation. I had (wrongly) assumed that `inCategories` meant it returned the results of all categories provided, from my interpretation of the name. I never thought it would be a logical AND between contents of that property's array, so didn't read on to see the explanation of using `nil`.